# Delete period after howpublished field in bibliography using natbib and agsm

Tags: natbib

I am using `natbib` with `agsm.bst` and \documentclass{book}

I have `howpublished` field in .bib `@misc` entry.

```
@misc{BHF2014,
annote = {[Accessed: July 2015]},
author = {{British Heart Foundation.}},
howpublished = {[Online] Available from},
title = {{Cardiovascular Disease Statistics 2014}},
url = {https://www.bhf.org.uk/publications/statistics/cardiovascular-disease-statistics-2014},
urldate = {July 2015},
year = {2014}
}
```

I have edited the `agsm.bst` to include `howpublished` before `url` in the bibliography

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " *output.nonnull
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.btitle "title" output.check }
  if$
  howpublished output
  new.block
  note output
  annote output
  write.url
  empty.misc.check
  fin.entry
}
```

but `agsm.bst` is outputting a period after the `howpublished` field ("Available from") in the bibliography.

[image]

I am trying to find out how to delete this period (after "Available from"). I assume the offending character is coming from `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}` but I cannot find exactly where.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post text code, not screenshots. Please also tell us which document class you use and which other citation- and bibliography-related packages you use (if any). In particular, do you load the `har2nat` package to improve the interoperability between the `agsm` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post, hope it's ok. I use the book document class and the only referencing  packages I use are {url} and [round]{natbib}